# How to find cause of (SIGABRT) heap corruption detected by dlmalloc_real?

Tags: android, sigabrt, heap-corruption

Sometimes, my application stops saying ->

```
A/libc: heap corruption detected by dlmalloc_real
        Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8614 (drotorres.uareu)
```

I'm tryng to track it, and resolve the cuase. My logcat out about the erros is that:

```
04-23 16:36:25.749 8614-8614/com.br.ufc.pedrotorres.uareu A/libc: heap corruption detected by dlmalloc_real
    Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8614 (drotorres.uareu)
04-23 16:36:25.859 395-395/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j5xnlteub/j5xnlte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J510MNVJU2AQI1:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '4'
    ABI: 'arm'
    pid: 8614, tid: 8614, name: drotorres.uareu  >>> com.br.ufc.pedrotorres.uareu <<<
    signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
04-23 16:36:25.879 395-395/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'heap corruption detected by dlmalloc_real'
        r0 00000000  r1 000021a6  r2 00000006  r3 b6f11b94
        r4 b6f11b9c  r5 b6f11b4c  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
        r8 be99b8fc  r9 be99b894  sl 12cd2400  fp ffffffff
        ip 00000006  sp be99b7a8  lr b6c90f15  pc b6c93310  cpsr 400f0010
04-23 16:36:25.889 395-395/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 00044310  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
        #01 pc 00041f11  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
        #02 pc 0001ba13  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
        #03 pc 00018c81  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
        #04 pc 00016840  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
        #05 pc 0001a627  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_fatal+16)
        #06 pc 0002e221  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_heap_corruption_error+8)
        #07 pc 0002f2bd  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc_real+628)
        #08 pc 000485a9  /system/lib/libc++.so (_Znwj+16)
        #09 pc 0010d319  /system/lib/libskia.so (_ZN16SkMallocPixelRef9NewDirectERK11SkImageInfoPvjP12SkColorTable+20)
        #10 pc 000e95eb  /system/lib/libskia.so (_ZN8SkBitmap9setPixelsEPvP12SkColorTable+30)
        #11 pc 0007f9f1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
        #12 pc 042dfd63  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x2fcf000)
04-23 16:36:26.309 395-395/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_09
04-23 16:36:26.309 395-395/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
```

Comment: Have you found the solution to this error?

Comment: unfortunately not.